# Pooling in mice package using weibreg() function

Tags: r, missing-data, survival-analysis, r-mice, weibull

I am using the `mice` package to impute a missing dataset that has a survival outcome. The failure time follows a Weibull distribution. So when I do the Weibull regression using a `weibreg` function it shows the following error.

```
mi_reg <- pool(with(mi, weibreg(Surv(start age, end age, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + factor(x5))))
```

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class weibreg

Since the time scale, I'm using here is the age, I would like to include both starting and stopping age in the `Surv()` function. So is there any alternate function for fitting a Weibull proportional hazard model for my data.

I don't know whether this info will be of any help, my response (start age, stop age, and event) does not have any missing value in it. Only the covariates have missing values.

Comment: Please provide `dput(mi)`, without your data it is very hard to answer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error has to do with a mismatch of the `pool` function and the `weibreg` function.